# Elements in a finite quotient group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups, quotient-group

The question is as follows:

Suppose that $K\mathrel{\unlhd}G$ with $|G/K|=n<\infty$.

1. Then $g^n\in K~\forall~g\in G$.
2. If $g\in G$ and $g^m\in K$ for some integer $m$ such that $\text{gcd}(m,n)=1$ then $g\in K$.

My attempt:

I have successfully proved 1, using the fact that $|G/K|=n\Rightarrow (gK)^n=K\Rightarrow g^nK=K\Rightarrow g^n\in K.$

Now, in the second part, I get that $g^n, g^m \in K$ so, $g^ng^m\in K$. Now, I was wondering if we could somehow use the fact $\exists~x,y\ni xm+yn=1.$ I'd appreciate some help in this part of the question.

Comment: Your idea for the second part is right on.

Comment: $g^n$ and $g^m$ are in $K$ thus $g=g^{xm+yn}=(g^m)^x(g^n)^y\in K$ and thats it

Comment: I'm new to group theory, so I'd appreciate it if you could provide me with proof of the fact that if $g^m\in K$ then, $(g^m)^x\in K$ as well, for some $x$?

Comment: In your notation, if $a\in K$, then $a^2\in K$, and so on, so $a^x\in K$ for all $x\ge 1$.

Comment: You should only ask one question at a time.